# What is $\limsup n^ne^{-n^{1.001}}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

During checking whether or not $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n^ne^{-n^{1.001}}}$ converges, I thought of trying the n-th root test. I got that $\sqrt[n]{n^ne^{-n^{1.001}}}=ne^{-n^{0.001}}$. How can I find $\limsup?$ I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t = n^{0.001}$, then we have the equivalent term of $ne^{n^{-0.001}}$, 
which is $t^{100}e^{-t}$.

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{t^{100}}{e^{t}} = \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{e^t} = 0
\end{align}

The first " = " comes from L'hopital's rule. (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html)

Answer (score 3):

Recall that, as $X\rightarrow +\infty$, you have
$$
\frac{\ln (X)}{X} \rightarrow 0
$$
and since $\displaystyle  e^{n^{0.001}}\rightarrow +\infty$ as $\displaystyle  n\rightarrow +\infty$, then 
$$
ne^{-n^{0.001}}=\frac{n}{e^{n^{0.001}}}=\frac{1}{0.001}\times \frac{\ln ({e^{n^{0.001}}})}{e^{n^{0.001}}}\rightarrow 0
$$ and **the desired $\limsup$ is equal to $0$.**

Comment: But ${n\over e^{n^{0.001}}}=e^{\ln(n)-n^{0.001}}$ and ${\ln(n)-n^{0.001}}$ tends to infinity. 
Can you show me how you got this form?

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel There is a mistake in your preceding comment, we rather have ${\ln(n)-n^{0.001}} \rightarrow -\infty$. Thanks.